# Rails behaving strange

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations

I have rails version `3.2.13` and ruby version `1.9.3`.

I have caught into very strange and interesting situation.

In my application have a model 'Product'  with custom validator.

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :price, :short_description, :user_id
  validates :name, :short_description, presence: true
  validates :price, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0}
  validate :uniq_name

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :original, foreign_key: :copied_from_id, class_name: 'Product'
  has_many :clones, foreign_key: :copied_from_id, class_name: 'Product', dependent: :nullify

  def clone?
    self.original ? true : false
  end

 private

 #Custom validator

 def uniq_name
   return if clone?
   user_product = self.user.products.unlocked.where(:name => self.name).first
   errors[:name] << "has already been taken" if user_product && !user_product.id.eql?(self.id)
 end

end
```

In products controller's create action when I am trying to create new product

```
def create
  @product = current_user.products.new(params[:product])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.save
      format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @product, status: :created, location: @product }
    else
      @product.errors[:image] = "Invalid file extension" if @product.errors[:image_content_type].present?
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
 end
end
```

Custom validator is being called when this line executed `@product = current_user.products.new(params[:product])` and  `line # 2` of custom validator giving me error

```
undefined method `products' for nil:NilClass
```

I have inspected product object in custom validator but `user_id` is nil.
Why `user_id` is not being autoassigned?

Your help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Try using `.build` instead of `.new`

Comment: Are you sure that it happens because of validation and not because current_user is nil? In your validation code everything is ok.

Comment: @gvalmon if it were nil user the error msg would be different - I wanted to write, but yeah, line is not specified

Comment: Ramiz can you add the line number and file for the error?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel He said that "Custom validator is being called when this line executed". but validator should not execute on initialization, that's why I think that issue related with current_user. Why do you think that error would be different? if current_user is nil, then he trying to call "products" on nil.

Comment: Your current_user is nil. Check if you are assigning the right value to the current_user.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel, @gvalmon -  Eror is same when i replaced `.new` with `build`. Any idea why validations are being called while building object?

Comment: Can you add full trace for this error?

Comment: Should your clone? method be reversed? If .original returns true, clone? returns true. If .original is false, clone? returns false. It seems like the opposite should happen.

Comment: @robotcookies - My `clone?` method is correct. If record has `copied_from_id` then it belongs to some original product. And if it belongs to some original product then It is a clone :) Thanks for showing concern in my Question :)

Answer (score 0):

So ... bypassing your question. Why aren't you just validating the uniqueness of name?

`validates_uniqueness_of :name, :unless => :clone?`

Answer (score 0):

try to change .new to .build

```
@product = current_user.products.build(params[:product])
```

and be sure that you have relation in your User model

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
```